# ajax запрос в внутри for django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Надо через input изменять цифру внутри input в базе данных templates но запрос отправляется на все и изменяется всё.

django

```
 {% for k in two %}
{% if k.user == userocenka %}


<input id="changetwo" class="inputOcenka" type="text" 
value="{{ k.ocenka }}">

<script>
    $('#changetwo').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/lessons/journal/change/{{ k.id }}/",
      data: 
      {
        texttwo: $('#changetwo').val(),
      },
      success: function(json){
        $('#changeinptwo').val(json.ocenka)
        console.log({{k.id}})
      }

});
});
</script>



{% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
    @csrf_exempt
def jachange(request, id=None):
    ochange = Gnahatakan.objects.get(id=id)
    ocenkad = request.POST.get('texttwo')
    if ocenkad != '':
        ochange.ocenka = ocenkad
        ochange.save()
        print(ochange.id)
    else:
        print(ochange.id)
        ochange.delete()
    return JsonResponse({ 'ocenka': ocenkad })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ надо вместо  changetwo ставить changetwo{{k.id}} чтобы он отличался.